# Return specific object in JSON array using swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

Using a struct I am getting data from JSON via a web API and I would like to print all of the data for a specific object e.g I would like to print all Product Id's from the response.

Here is my code:

```
    struct Varients: Decodable {
    let ProductId: String
    let Colour: String
    let name: String
}

struct varientsResponse: Decodable {
    let varients: [Varients]
}
```

View Controller:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.113:8000/getvarient/?url=https://www.prettylittlething.com/stone-abstract-marble-print-structured-corset.html")
    guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }
    // Create URL Request
    var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
    // Specify HTTP Method to use
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        
        // Check if Error took place
        if let error = error {
            print("Error took place \(error)")
            return
        }
        
        // Read HTTP Response Status code
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print("Response HTTP Status code: \(response.statusCode)")
        }
        
        // Convert HTTP Response Data to a simple String
        if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            let varientResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(varientsResponse.self, from: data)
            print(varientResponse)
            
            
       
        }
        
    }
    task.resume()
```

JSON Response Example:

```
  "varients": [
    {
      "ProductId": "1703412",
      "Colour": "Stone",
      "Sizes": [
        "4",
        "6",
        "8",
        "10",
        "12",
        "14",
        "16"
      ],
      "image": "https://cdn-img.prettylittlething.com/2/7/f/4/27f4825ee181668f1e8e5797478607b505dbee1c_cmt4421_1.jpg?imwidth=1024",
      "name": "Stone  Abstract Marble Print Structured Corset"
    },
    {
      "ProductId": "865801",
      "Colour": "Pastel Orange",
      "Sizes": [
        "4",
        "6",
        "8",
        "10",
        "12",
        "14",
        "16"
      ],
      "image": "https://cdn-img.prettylittlething.com/e/b/e/6/ebe60bba9afe0fc20fabbb5db34494dcd688dc4b_CMF1440_1.jpg?imwidth=1024",
      "name": "Orange Tie Dye Print Structured Corset Top"
    },
    {
      "ProductId": "867743",
      "Colour": "Purple",
      "Sizes": [
        "4",
        "6",
        "8",
        "10",
        "12",
        "14",
        "16"
      ],
      "image": "https://cdn-img.prettylittlething.com/d/a/8/3/da83149d0c6e00e094e417f3ed2d4b15927d15a9_CMF1829_1.jpg?imwidth=1024",
      "name": "Purple Tie Dye Print Structured Corset Top"
    },
    {
      "ProductId": "979950",
      "Colour": "Fuchsia",
      "Sizes": [
        "4",
        "6",
        "8",
        "10",
        "12",
        "14",
        "16"
      ],
      "image": "https://cdn-img.prettylittlething.com/a/0/e/2/a0e2d0847f64ee961388272009203461ee7028ee_cmg7868_1.jpg?imwidth=1024",
      "name": "Fuschia Tie Dye Print Structured Corset Top"
    },
    {
      "ProductId": "1083745",
      "Colour": "Acid Blue Wash",
      "Sizes": [
        "4",
        "6",
        "8",
        "10",
        "12",
        "14",
        "16"
      ],
      "image": "https://cdn-img.prettylittlething.com/b/e/7/4/be744c7f8fef860182ea730572c3f1dfb8b4820e_cmk5407_1.jpg?imwidth=1024",
      "name": "Blue Tie Dye Print Structured Corset Top"
    },
    {
      "ProductId": "1083753",
      "Colour": "Light Pink",
      "Sizes": [
        "4",
        "6",
        "8",
        "10",
        "12",
        "14",
        "16"
      ],
      "image": "https://cdn-img.prettylittlething.com/f/c/8/7/fc8700bbd28684d418f4ed49b638bda9112b1aca_cmk5405_1.jpg?imwidth=1024",
      "name": "Light Pink Tie Dye Print Structured Corset Top"
    },
    {
      "ProductId": "1450163",
      "Colour": "Turquoise",
      "Sizes": [
        "4",
        "6",
        "8",
        "10",
        "12",
        "14",
        "16"
      ],
      "image": "https://cdn-img.prettylittlething.com/6/6/6/f/666fc73c32602aa964f69d65fee2e3f77198448d_cmp4910_1.jpg?imwidth=1024",
      "name": "Turquoise Marble Print Structured Corset Top"
    },
    {
      "ProductId": "1667090",
      "Colour": "Pink",
      "Sizes": [
        "4",
        "6",
        "8",
        "10",
        "12",
        "14",
        "16"
      ],
      "image": "https://cdn-img.prettylittlething.com/f/8/a/8/f8a85d97fe670e37ec5903d435e1ac44ecad8fd7_cms8800_1.jpg?imwidth=1024",
      "name": "Pink Abstract Renaissance Print Structured Corset"
    },
    {
      "ProductId": "1698866",
      "Colour": "Monochrome",
      "Sizes": [
        "4",
        "6",
        "8",
        "10",
        "12",
        "14",
        "16"
      ],
      "image": "https://cdn-img.prettylittlething.com/f/7/a/a/f7aa8247197d6dcfc8f8bd270d7b50626e857d62_cmt3674_1.jpg?imwidth=1024",
      "name": "Black Zebra Print Structured Corset Top"
    },
    {
      "ProductId": "1703508",
      "Colour": "Green",
      "Sizes": [
        "4",
        "6",
        "8",
        "10",
        "12",
        "14",
        "16"
      ],
      "image": "https://cdn-img.prettylittlething.com/c/b/d/f/cbdf70eaa970a1ffaa3f3b54e9b7c4173ee0c560_cmt4422_1.jpg?imwidth=1024",
      "name": "Green  Abstract Marble Print Structured Corset"
    }
  ]
}
```

I can return the varientsResponse but I obviously get the full JSON response, I can also return the varientsResponse.varients[0].productId but I would like to be able to get a full array of all productID's in the JSON

Comment: `print(varientResponse.variants.map(\.ProductId))`

Comment: Perfect that's working now, how would I map the productID to the colour? Basically I am showing the Colours in a drop down and once the user makes their selection it will save it to a DB but I also need to save the product ID for that colour selection.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your initial question and then also your follow up question in the comments.

You can access the Colour and the ID for a specific item like this:

```
varientResponse.variants.map { varient in 
  
  // Save to database by accessing like this:
  // Colour - varient.Colour
  // ID - varient.ProductID

}
```

Unrelated to your question, but normally Structs are named as singular. Which makes sense as each instance of your struct will be a singular `Varient`.

Comment: Thanks for your response Joshua, am I right in thinking I could use the vairentResponse.variants.map {

}
to map the productId to the colour?

Comment: Yep, you could even use your already existing struct for this, inside the map something like `let myVarient = Varient(ProductId: varient.ProductId, Color: varient.Color, Name: varient.name)` and just send your database `myVarient`. If you want to send multiple variants at once you might consider pushing your instance of Varient to an array of Varients and sending that to your backend.

Comment: When I print:  let myVarient = (varientNew.Colour + " " + "(\(varientNew.ProductId))") it shows both variants of the product but when I show it on the app to the user as an array I only get one product